# JQuery .change works but .keyup does not

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to bind some functions to some input fields. The weird part is, if I add the `.change` event to the inputs it fires just fine but when I add the '.keyup' on the same inputs the event does not fire.

Note: Yes the inputs are found in a document ready function. I also commented out the `.unbind` method and that did not fix the issue. The only reason that is there is so I can call the this method later and the inputs will not be bound twice.

here is what I am using:

```
bindInputChange: function()
{
    var inputs = jQuery(':input');
    if(inputs != null)
    {
        inputs.unbind();
    }

    inputs.change(function() { alert('change called'); }); // this one works
    inputs.keyup(function() { alert('keyup called'); }); // this one does not
},
```

any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: I tried a version of this in a fiddle, and it works fine (both events are being triggered). http://jsfiddle.net/CjGc7/

Comment: @zachstarnes, try unfocussing the input after changing somethin

Comment: Change is triggered when you leave the input field (and the value has changed)

Comment: @AmitJoki would it make a difference that this is in an object?

Comment: Nope - http://jsfiddle.net/CjGc7/1/

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in the console?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I have another function that makes anything you type uppercase and that function has an `.unbind` which was removing the `.keyup`. After removing the `.unbind` everything worked. Thanks for all the help!